# Given a Configuration object, how can I create a PropertiesConfiguration object?

Tags: java, configuration, properties-file, apache-commons-config

I have a method that returns a Configuration object. I need to instantiate a PropertiesConfig object to save this to disk. How can I do so?

Comment: Read the "saving" section here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/howto_properties.html

Comment: Thanks - I've read that, but the Config object I have is actually a CombinedConfiguration, and has no save method. I need to 'converet' it to a properties config and save it as a properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using copy method? This example works for me:

```
    XMLConfiguration conf1 = new XMLConfiguration("table1.xml");
    XMLConfiguration conf2 = new XMLConfiguration("table2.xml");

    // Create and initialize the node combiner
    NodeCombiner combiner = new UnionCombiner();
    combiner.addListNode("table");  // mark table as list node
                // this is needed only if there are ambiguities

    // Construct the combined configuration
    CombinedConfiguration cc = new CombinedConfiguration(combiner);
    cc.addConfiguration(conf1, "tab1");
    cc.addConfiguration(conf2);

    PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("usergui.properties");

    config.copy(cc);
    config.save();
```